# Power Automate Flow HTTP request: know when flow is done

Tags: python, http, python-requests, power-automate

I am triggering my Power Automate Flow with an HTTP request send thru pythons request module. The response I get is 202, what stands for request is accepted to processing.

How can I make python wait until Power Automate is finished or alternatively is there a way to to make Power Automate send additional response when Flow is finished ?

EDIT the code for triggering Flow

```
>>> flow0_url = 'url_to_trigger_pa_flow'
>>> requests.post(flow0_url)
Out[10]: <Response [202]>
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: The returned 202 response should include a JSON body that has a job ID.  You can send a request with the job id that checks the status.  Microsoft docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/web-api

Comment: Change your second line to `res = requests.post(flow0_url)`, then call `res.json()`

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this out but get an error when trying to `res.json()`: `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`. The flow executes without an error. Should I configure the response JSON on the Power Automate Side ?

Comment: Have you added a Response action at the end of your flow with a HTTP 200? Below article might also be useful for this scenario: https://d365demystified.com/2021/03/22/asynchronous-http-response-from-a-flow-power-automate/

Comment: Thanks now it works, my requests is running until getting the response when flow is finished, thanks!